# Trying to debug an app but getting Error: No named parameter with the name 'vsync'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/stacked-3.2.1/lib/src/view_models/ui/skeleton_loader.dart:105:19: Error: No named parameter with the name 'vsync'.
                  vsync: this,
                  ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_size.dart:28:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const AnimatedSize({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

Comment: Very simple, vsync no longer exists in the AnimatedSize widget, upgrading the package will probably solve it, if it still doesn't solve it, download the 3.2.1 release of this package and change it yourself.

Comment: Looking at the latest version of this package, fixed vsync in animatedSize. [You can see it here](https://github.com/Stacked-Org/stacked/blob/master/lib/src/view_models/ui/skeleton_loader.dart).

Answer (score 0):

```
class SkeletonLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  // the rest of your code here 
}

class _SkeletonLoaderState extends State<SkeletonLoader> with 
TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // the rest of your code here 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSize(
      duration: _resizeDuration,
      // the rest of your code here 
      // remove vsync: this
    );
  }
}
```